# Is something like this possible in CUDA

Tags: c++, c, cuda, counter

Let's say, I have a matrix with values of 0 or 1. It is in CUDA possible, to do something like this:

```
__global__ void kernel(float *matrix, float *count)
{
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int column = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (row >= MATRIXSIZE || column >= MATRIXSIZE)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (matrix[MATRIXSIZE * row + column] == 1)
    {
        count[0]++;
    }
}
```

So I get in the end ne number of ones in the matrix. I know, this is very simple example, but if this might be possible, so also other variants ...

Comment: You have to be aware that every thread are gonna run this kernel and then they will write at the same adress `count[0]`, you might build a result vector which has the size of your grid and each thread has his own location on this vector. so you can make any operation on it without being disturbed by other threads. Then operate a reduction over it.

Comment: @user3018144: How to do such reduction?

Comment: You can look for mark harris pattern reduction: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf or I heard that there's an other way to perform quick reduction via shuffle function in CUDA. You can also take a look at it.

Comment: yeah, you should sum along the columns (or rows) across threads, then sum the resulting vector afterwards. Also leave out the branch, and just use the actual memory for the sum. Branches are slow even in cuda.

Answer (score 4):

There are highly optimized libraries for CUDA that perform these types of operations, called reductions. Look into CUDA Thrust or CUB. In Thrust, you can use `reduce` to sum up all the values or `count` to count number of instances of a particular value.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this. You should use atomic add: [atomicadd](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions). `atomicadd(count[0],1)`

But this may cause performance issue.

Comment: It should be `atomicAdd(count, 1)`.